# Assigning a class field of type class through the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to create a map of nodes, storing their current position, as well as the surrounding nodes.

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node up;
    public Node down;
    
}

//Declare nodes within inspector
public Node[] map;
```

I know this can be achieved at runtime, or by using ScriptableObjects, but can I declare each Node's fields within the inspector?

As they are not shown unlike the Vector2 property
[image: Inspector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible display the fields in editor if you wrap the recurring class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public NodeMap nodeMap;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class NodeMap
{
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node up;
    public Node down;
}

public class Nodes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Node[] map;
}
```

But you will get the following warning as there is no way to know where the nesting ends. You should test if serialization works fine or not before you hit 10 levels deep.

That's why they require a MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject assignment as the nesting can stop as soon as you leave one unassigned.

> Serialization depth limit 10 exceeded at
> 'Node.nodeMap'. There may be an object
> composition cycle in one or more of your serialized classes.

> Serialization depth limit 10 exceeded at
> 'NodeMap.left'. There may be an object
> composition cycle in one or more of your serialized classes.

As you can see here the nesting ends at 10th level of nodeMap-left-nodeMap-left...

[image: Unity nested serialization with wrapper]

Comment: Very nice, I would only reach a depth of one, so perfect. But, I ended up using the ScriptableObjects as a temporary solution. But I'll keep this in-mind for the future, thanks!

Comment: @Luc anyway this won't really help you at all ... as you see the Serialization limit kicks in and what is worse: you can't reference these Nodes as Subnodes of multiple other nodes .. with ScriptaleObject you can! If you went with the ScriptableObject solution .. may I ask why you accepted this as the answer then? ;)

Comment: @derHugo I was using ScriptableObjects as a temporary solution, hoping to find another method. But as it took a while to setup for ~80 nodes I stuck with it. But this solution actually answers my original question, with assignment through the inspector

Comment: @Luc as said not really ... yes you can this way set the Vector fields but the entire system fails in case you need one node referenced in two other nodes as subnode ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unity limits the serialization of the same type for serializable classes to one level!

See [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

> Note: Unity does not support serialization of multilevel types (multidimensional arrays, jagged arrays, and nested container types). If you want to serialize these, you have two options: wrap the nested type in a class or struct, or use serialization callbacks ISerializationCallbackReceiver to perform custom serialization. For more information, see documentation on Custom Serialization.

So even if you could add them all they might not be saved in the end!

---

I would not go the [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) route in your case.

You should rather use [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) like

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Node", menuName = "MyStuff/Node")]
public class Node : ScriptableObject
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node up;
    public Node down;   
}
```

And now you simply <kbd>Right Click</kbd> in the `Assets`(Project View) → <kbd>MyStuff</kbd> → <kbd>Node</kbd> to create your `Node` instances and can then reference them to each other.

Comment: Damn that's a shame, I was hoping there was a method that I was forgetting

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define the connecting Nodes within the inspector and instead refer to the Nodes held elsewhere, then they will need to be ScriptableObjects or MonoBehaviours that you can drag & drop into the field.